# Is it possible to add input control(s) to OpenCV's viz?

Tags: c++, user-interface, opencv

I have a visualizer program that displays all images in the 3D space using `viz3d` (in C++). The code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
    //Parsing input & computation...
    if (bSuccess) {
        VisualizeWithViz()
    } else printf("Something went wrong, blah blah")
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, `viz3d` is initialized, configured, and then span inside `VisualizeWithViz()`.

However, I want to make the program reconfigurable while the visualizer is open (instead of giving the inputs via batch script). I was wondering if it's possible to add simple edit controls into the visualizer.

Alternatively, if there's a way to integrate the visualizer inside GUI built with MFC, that would also be great.